# Wide div - can I get rid of scrollbars somehow?

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

I have a wide div that has background image. The div is 1100px wide and when browser window is less than that, theres scrollbars. Is there any ways to avoid the  scrollbars? Thats isnt any hack. Now I know I could put it in body image, but I would like to have it this div for a reason.

```
<body>
<div id="imgWrapper"> <-the wide div the image
<div id="wrapper"> <- normal 960px wrapper
<div id="content"> <- content inside this
Blablabla......
</div>
</div>
</body>
```

But ofcourse if the contnet inside that #container/#content is wider than the browser window than I want scrollbars.

Comment: So...you want scrollbars but you don't want them? Could you clarify exactly what you're after?

Answer (score 3):

Use `overflow:hidden` or `overflow:auto`.

There are also variations for each axis ,`overflow-x:` and `overflow-y:` with the same properties (`hidden`, `visible`, and `auto`).

Answer (score 0):

To suppress scrollbars, use the CSS `overflow` (which controls both vertical and horizontal scrollbars; use `overflow-x` and `overflow-y` for individual scollbar control) property on your divs: http://www.w3schools.com/Css/pr_pos_overflow.asp

Answer (score 0):

alternatively, you can also drop div#imgWrapper from your html, and give #wrapper a css background.

```
<body>
 <div id="wrapper"> <- normal 960px wrapper
 <div id="content"> <- content inside this
  Blablabla......
 </div>
 </div>
</body>
```

css

```
#wrapper { background: url(path/to/someimage.png) transparent 0 0 no-repeat;
```